# Installing numpy-1.7.1 with MKL-10.3 using gcc-4.7.2 on linux

Tags: python, numpy, openmp, intel-mkl

I have been trying to install `numpy-1.7.1` with `MKL-10.3` on `python-2.7.5` using `gcc-4.7.2` on a `linux-2.6.18-308.24.1.el5` system for a few days now. I have not long ago successfully compiled `R-3.0.1` with `MKL` using the same compiler.

I modified the `site.cfg` file in `numpy-1.7.1` as follows:

```
[mkl]
library_dirs = /sb/software/libraries/MKL/10.3/lib/intel64
include_dirs = /sb/software/libraries/MKL/10.3/include
mkl_libs = mkl_rt
lapack_libs =
```

When I call `python setup.py install`, it finds the `MKL` libraries for `BLAS` and `LAPACK`. Up until this point, there is no complaint or warning. It breaks down once I try to do something with `numpy`.

```
 $ python
 Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 31 2013, 16:54:43)
 [GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import numpy
 >>> numpy.test('full')
 Running unit tests for numpy
 NumPy version 1.7.1
 NumPy is installed in /sb/project/mjd-574/ndejay/modules/python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
 Python version 2.7.5 (default, Jul 31 2013, 16:54:43) [GCC 4.7.2]
 nose version 1.3.0
 .................python: symbol lookup error: /sb/software/libraries/MKL/10.3/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so: undefined symbol: omp_get_num_procs
```

This appears to be a known issue ([link to source](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/a-new-linking-model-single-dynamic-library-mkl_rt-since-intel-mkl-103)) whereby `libiomp5` is not loaded by `libmkl_rt`. When I add the path to `libiomp5` to the `library_dirs` variable in `site.cfg`, `numpy` fails to detect *all* `MKL` libraries.

I have even tried the following to force `gcc` to use its own `openMP` libraries/headers, but to no avail.

```
CFLAGS='-fopenmp -lgomp' python setup.py install
```

I would be grateful for any sort of help or advice on this matter. Do not hesitate to let me know I have omitted critical information in this thread.

EDIT: I am running on a `x86_64` platform.

Comment: Are you using `mkl` without `icc`? `libiomp5` is in `$INTEL_PATH/intel/lib/`, I do not see it linked.

Comment: I am not using `icc`. Do you think therein lies the problem? I have compiled `R` with `MKL` recently using `gcc` without any issues.

Comment: Its unlikely to be the problem, but `libiomp5` is something that I usually miss- including that directory specifically should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the path to `libiomp5` to the `LD_MODULES_PATH` environment.  The servers I am currently using use the `modules` library to manage server-wide applications and libraries. I had previously only used the *standalone* `MKL/10.3` module but substituting that for `ifort_icc/13.0` (which also contains `MKL`) added `icc`-related paths to the `LD_MODULES_PATH`. Using the same `site.cfg` as described above seems to work and `numpy` runs the test suite.

I don't know if this is the most elegant solution but it will do the trick for now.

Comment: Did you have to recompile? I'm running into the exact same issue. I've set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to look at both lib folders to no avail. LD_MODULES_PATH doesn't seem to be set on our system (which is also using the modules library).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to libomp5: composer_xe_install_path/compiler/lib/intel64
 to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. For me the path looks like: /opt/apps/intel/16.1/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.150/linux/compiler/lib/intel64